# What Does The String '{?District}' evaluate to in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, string

I have the following SQL query I was given, but I am not sure which flavor of SQL it is.

```
Select *     
From myTable Z
WHERE Z.code = '{?District}'
```

Is '{?District}' an expression or is it just a string with some strange characters in it? I could not find anything online about special meanings for those characters in a SQL String.

Comment: I found out that this was code from a crystal report and the {?District} is a parameter in the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a string.

Try executing the following:

```
select '{?District}'
```

The result set simply returns `{?District}`

Answer (score 1):

I would think that it is a strange string. I can see that has some special meaning of it.

Answer (score 1):

This string has no special meaning in any version of MS SQL Server through 2008 R2 (and probably including 2012, I doubt you're looking at code specifically written for that).

Answer (score 0):

{?District} is not an expression.  You are comparing if Z.Code matches that string.